# What does " the shuffle done right" mean or refer to in the passage?

Tags: meaning

What does "shuffle done right" mean or refer to in the passage?

> Do yourself a favor. Go to YouTube and
> search for ‘‘Magic Slim Goin’ to Mississippi Blind Pig 2011.’’ The video shows
> blues fundamentalist Magic Slim recording a song with his band, the
> Teardrops, in the warehouse of his record label two years ago. He was still
> going strong then at age 73, despite
> chronic heart and lung ailments.
> In the video he plays a straight blues
> shuffle, the kind of thing played every
> day by millions of musicians all over
> the world. But it’s a **shuffle done right**, a
> form lastingly codified in the 1950s during the golden age of Chicago blues and
> perfected by Magic Slim over the
> course of a musical lifetime. And a
> shuffle played right is a truly satisfying
> — and deceptively rare — thing.
> (New York Times) Carlo Rotella

Comment: Not any attempt at an answer, just some background from a musician. It is generally held as 'true' amongst musicians that there are a thousand ways to play a shuffle or swing - any style where the notes have an uneven timing, somewhere between straight 8s and triplets - 'wrong' and very few ways to play it 'right' [correctly]. Humans are very poor at diving by 3 perceptually, so this 'skill' of being able to subdivide by something 'not quite three' raises a lot of opinion. It's also believed that classical musicians are the worst at this & jazz musicians the best.

Comment: One disparaging comment made about this inability to shuffle or swing is characterised by the phrase, "He couldn't swing from a rope." Much of this is characterised by nothing more definitive than 'feel'. It has nothing you could measure mathematically. A good musician in this genre just 'knows' when it's right & a poor one doesn't know when it's wrong.

Comment: "done right" = "performed properly"

Answer (score 1):

It simply means *a shuffle that has been done the right way*.

A "shuffle", in this context, means:

> **3 c (1) :** a rhythm where each beat of the measure is played as a triplet with the first and second parts of the triplet tied and the third part accented
> **(2) :** music played in a shuffle rhythm

So it means a piece of music that has a shuffle rhythm, and that is played the right way.

The context doesn't say what "the right way" is to play a shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

> ...he plays a straight blues shuffle, the kind of thing played every day by millions of musicians all over the world. But it’s a shuffle done right, a form lastingly codified in the 1950s during the golden age of Chicago blues and perfected by Magic Slim over the course of a musical lifetime.
> And a shuffle played right is a truly satisfying — and deceptively rare — thing.

The *shuffle* is one way to play the guitar to create a special feel.

[shuffle](https://bestbluesguitarlessonsonline.com/bluesshuffle#:%7E:text=The%20shuffle%20is%20a%20specific,to%20create%20that%20special%20feel.)

> The shuffle is a specific eighth note rhythmic feel. It is based on triplets rather than dividing the beat in half in a strait eighth note rhythm.

*shuffle done right* just means that the player does it right/correctly.